# How to add reference Parameters in extend_schema decorator in drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm using [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate the swagger/redoc API documentation.

I am facing issue in customising the schemas generated. I am trying to generate reference parameter using @extend_schema decorators in drf_spectacular but did'nt get the expected schema.

extend_schema -

```
`
 from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema
 @extend_schema(
    parameters=headerParam,
    responses = {200:Response1,400:errorresponse},
    tags = ['User'],
)`
```

headerParam -

```
`headerParam = [
    OpenApiParameter(
        name='Accept-Language', 
        location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
        type=OpenApiTypes.STR,
        description='ISO 2 Letter Language Code',
        required=True,
        enum=['en', 'ar'],
        # default='en',
    ),
    OpenApiParameter(
        name='Accept', 
        location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER,
        type=OpenApiTypes.STR,
        description='Type of response you are expecting from API. i.e. (application/json)',
        required=True,
        default='application/json',
    ),
]`
```

I am generating json schema by using "SpectacularJSONAPIView", but the problem I am facing is the schema in drf_spectacular is generating this as below -

```
`"parameters": [
      {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "Accept",
            "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "application/json"
            },
            "description": "Type of response you are expecting from API. i.e (application/json)",
            "required": true
       },
       {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
               "ar",
               "en"
             ]
            },
            "description": "ISO 2 Letter Language Code",
            "required": true
       }
 ],`
```

I want to generate like this in the headerparams -

```
 "parameters": [
     {
         "$ref": "#/components/parameters/Accept"
     },
     {
         "$ref": "#/components/parameters/Accept-Language"
     }
  ],`
```

In app side swagger generator(ios), he is asking me to pass these parameters as a reference parameter(given above) so that he should not pass this parameter all the time.

Thank you and Appreciate for the help in Advance :)

I have done R&D but didn't find anything related to this.